# Need to access array in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to access array in SQL Server while using insert command.
`@slted` has values like (`1,2,3`) these value is used to insert the no. of rows

```
alter proc usp_sltedAssign       
    @slted nvarchar, @curentMenuID bigint
as begin        
   insert into Table301 (FLD119,FLD232,FLD9)
   values('1', @curentMenuID, @slted)    
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your array as an xml string, the use the XML functionality within SQL to parse out and insert into a table- or what ever you want to do

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very precise, but you might find what you're looking for by using [TVPs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Basically you can pass complete tables as parameters to queries, and then use them like normal table variables.